# Wso2Esb : Message processor issue

Tags: wso2-esb

I have a strange behaviour with the message processing inside a message store.

I have a proxy service that put messages in a Message-Store and a Message-Processor that gets the messages from the Message-Store and call an endpoint.

If the message is correctly processed a sequence is called; in this sequence I launch an update query to a table.

Well, sending  500/1000, without any delay, to the message store I noticed that the Sequence with the query is not always called and no error is written in the Log.

If I deactive the Message-Processor and letting that Message-Store is filled by 500/1000 messages, reactiving the Message-Processor the sequence is always correctly called.

Do you know if there are some issues about Message-Processor ( my Message-Processor is a Scheduled type) when it must process a lot of messages at the same time ?

Moreover, how many Message-Processor instances Wso2Esb use to process the messages contained in the Message-Store ? ( one or more ? ).

If the are different instances of Message-Processor probably there is a Thread concurrent problem.

Cheers.

```
            warxsg
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the ESB version you are using. And can you tell me the what is the message processor you are using ? ex : MessageForwading processor ?  Sampling processor?

http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/10/implementing-store-forward-messaging-patterns-wso2esb-part-1 and 
http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/12/implementing-store-forward-messaging-patterns-wso2esb-part-2

might be helpfull.

cheers,